# When using the acts_as_votable gem, how do I perform an action after saving a vote?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mixpanel

I'm using the `acts_as_votable` gem in my Rails project to allow authenticated users to up/downvote posts.

Whenever a user places a vote, a vote event is logged using Mixpanel, an event logging service.  I'd like to ensure that a vote event is submitted only when a vote is saved.  That is, if a user has already voted, the event shouldn't get logged again.

Given that `acts_as_votable` is a gem, what is the best practice in this scenario?  Should I reopen the class or fork the gem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you believe you need to extend the functionality of `acts_as_votable` a better practice would be to reopen the class (monkey-patch). It will be more maintainable in the long run.

But the best practice is to stay away from `acts_as_votable` and modify your logging code. `acts_as_votable` has a `vote_registered?` method that tells you if the vote was saved, so your method could look like:

```
post.liked_by current_user
Mixpanel.submit 'new vote' if post.vote_registered?
```